# Prove that $H$ is a system of representatives for the cosets of $N$ in $G$, and that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a group and let $N \subseteq G$ be a normal subgroup. Suppose that there is a subgroup
$H \subseteq G$ such that

$HN = G$ with $HN = \{hn : h \in H, n \in N\}$,

$H \cap N = \{e\}$.

Prove that $H$ is a system of representatives for the cosets of $N$ in $G$, and that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $H$. ($G/N \cong H$)

I have no clue how to do this

Comment: Then let’s work through it! We want to prove that $G/N \cong H$. First, we should understand $G/N$. What does $G/N$ look like? What are its elements?

Comment: G/N is the set of left cosets of N and looks like this. For$ g_a$ in G G/N={$g_1N,g_2N,......,g_kN$} all left cosets of N in G

Comment: Okay, perfect! Now, we want to use some more of the properties we’ve been given. If all the elements of $G/N$ look like $gN$ for $g\in G$, what can we say if we know that $HN = G$?

Comment: Hi @SantanaAfton I did the first part of the question. I was wondering if could look whether my proof is ok?

Comment: @TWstud Great question! What you should do is post an answer to this question with your proof, and @ me if you’d like. Typically, this is a good way to have your proof checked!

Answer (score 0):

I would start by showing that $$G=\bigcup_{h\in H}hN,$$ and that for any $h_1,h_2\in H,$ we have $h_1N=h_2N$ if and only if $h_1=h_2.$ From there, the isomorphism $G/N\to H$ is almost trivial to define and justify.

Let me know if you're unsure about how to accomplish any of these steps, or if you just want to check if your reasoning is correct.